Is it possible to find all descendants of a type transitively, including implementations of a generic type?
Please before voting to close as a duplicate read carefully the description of the problem.
Given a class type, I need to discover its full hierarchy, including both the base and derived classes. The one requirement that throws a wrench in the gears is that open generic types are to be included in the result set in either direction.
Given a set of classes like class A, B<T>: A, C: B<int> and D<T>: C, E: D<int>, the result of the hypothetical DiscoverTypeTree(typeof(C)) is [A, B<>, B<int>] for its parent types and [D<>, D<int>, E] for derived types. Although this hierarchy is strictly vertical, the derived types should include all child types transitively.
Where I am stuck is that I can't seem to find a way to consistently include the open generic types in the output together with their concrete versions. In different iterations I either failed to discover all derived types when open generics were involved, or would only include the concrete types skipping the open generics in the result, or some other issues with missing types. I'm stuck now with the "would only include the concrete types skipping the open generics in the result" problem. So for the example above the incorrect result is that of [A, B<int>] and [D<int>, E].
The code (the language version is 13 and I target .NET 8; this is written as a local function):
var hierarchies = new Dictionary<Type, LinkedList<Type>>();
var derivedTypes = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<Type>>();
void discoverHierarchy<T>()
    where T : class {
    void _discover(Type type) {
        if (!hierarchies.ContainsKey(type)) {
            var hierarchy = new LinkedList<Type>();
            hierarchies.Add(type, hierarchy);

            var t2 = type;
            do {
                _ = hierarchy.AddFirst(t2);
                _discover(t2);
                t2 = t2.BaseType;
            }
            while (t2 is not null && t2 != typeof(object));

            var derived = new List<Type>();
            var def = type.IsGenericTypeDefinition ? type : null;
            if (def is not null && def != type) {
                _discover(def);
            }
            foreach (var t in assemblyTypes) // Cached output of `assembly.GetTypes()`.
            {
                if (t.IsSubclassOf(type)) {
                    derived.Add(t);
                    _discover(t);
                } else {
                    var t3 = t;
                    var list3 = new List<Type>();
                    do {
                        list3.Add(t3);
                        if (t3.BaseType?.IsGenericType is true && t3.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == def) {
                            derived.AddRange(list3);
                            foreach (var _t3 in list3) {
                                _discover(_t3);
                            }
                            break;
                        } else {
                            t3 = t3.BaseType;
                        }
                    }
                    while (t3 is not null);
                }
            }
            _ = derivedTypes.TryAdd(type, []);
            derivedTypes[type].AddRange(derived);
        }
    };

    var type = typeof(T);
    _discover(type);
}


Your tree is not vertical.  B<int> is not a descendant of B<>, and I would argue that B<> is not a parent of C<int>.  B<> and B<int> are two different and essentially incompatible types.  Your question strikes me as quite odd.  What good would it do for you to have this information?

When you get B<int>, you can make B<>, I don't understand why this could be the wrench, or don't you know Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition?

@TimRoberts: I know that by the rules of the language they are not related types in the terms of type relationship. But I want them to be included as if they were the base class of the derived types.

@shingo: I know that and if you read the code you could see I make use of the function. The "wrench" refers to how much more complicated the code becomes compared to just finding all concrete classes making up the hierarchy.

Maybe I'm overthinking this and miss the obvious, IDK, I'm too tired to think clearly now.

If you are going to make up your own rules about types, you should add that into your question. What other rules have you made up?

@Sweeper: this was in the question from the start.

I wrote an enumerable method that should be clear. It has three parts: self, parent types, and child types. If a generic type is found during the iteration, its generic type definition is also returned. The child type part needs an additional getting of its constructed base type.
static IEnumerable<Type> DiscoverTypeTree<T>(IEnumerable<Type> allTypes)
                         where T : class
{
    // self
    var t0 = typeof(T);
    if(t0 == typeof(object))
        yield break;
    yield return t0;
    if(t0.IsGenericType)
        yield return t0.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    
    // parent types
    var t1 = t0.BaseType;
    while(t1 != typeof(object))
    {
        yield return t1;
        if(t1.IsGenericType)
            yield return t1.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        t1 = t1.BaseType;
    }
    
    // child types
    foreach (var t2 in allTypes)
    {
        if(t2.IsAssignableTo(t0) && t0 != t2 && t2.IsClass)
        {
            yield return t2;
            if(t2.IsGenericType)
                yield return t2.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            
            // constructed base type, e.g. D<int>
            var t3 = t2.BaseType;
            if(t3 != t0 && !t3.ContainsGenericParameters)
                yield return t3;
        }
    }
}


Thanks for answering, but I couldn't make good use of your code because it is done in a weird way and the logic is not fully clear to me, like the code under the last comment, for example.

For example if you want to get a result of type C, you can call DiscoverTypeTree<C>(assemblyTypes).ToList(). The code under the last comment is going to return D<int>, because this type is not included in allTypes, but it need to be obtained from E.

I ended up making this a two stage process. But first I fixed the remaining bugs and significantly simplified the _discover() function. After the initial discovery of all given types' hierarchies and filling the two dictionaries I go through each hierarchy in hierarchies backwards, for each concrete generic type I insert the corresponding open generic type, and at last the same is done for each type in derivedTypes where I check if an open generic type is the parent of another type and copy the latter's derived types. Not as elegant as I'd want but does the job.
